# Check all check boxes and check specific check box in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this **javascript** function for checking all check box...it's working fine but if I want to check a specific check box 1 or 2 or more then I get an array of all but I didn't get specific check box value please tell me if any function in javascript or jQuery exists to do this.

```
var checkflag = "false";

function check(field) {
  if (checkflag == "false") {
      for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
          field[i].checked = true;
      }
      checkflag = "true";
      return "Uncheck All";
  } else {
      for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
          field[i].checked = false;
      }
      checkflag = "false";
      return "Check All";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check if checked or not

```
$('checkbox')[i].is(':checked');
$('checkbox')[i].not(':checked');
```

or

```
$('checkbox')[i].attr('checked') == 'checked';
$('checkbox')[i].attr('checked') !== 'checked';
```

then i think this works anyway:

```
field[i].checked == true;
field[i].checked == false;
```

but you have to use `==` not `=`